# Set default value for function

Tags: python

I created function which parses JSON file for subtask issue. Depending of number of tickets, this function sometimes return 1, sometimes more lines and sometimes returns nothing.

```
 def subtask():
     for issue in data['issues']:
      for subtask in issue['fields']['subtasks']:
        if subtask['fields']['summary'] != 'Workspace created':
          x = subtask['fields']['summary']
     return x
```

Next I pass output of this variable to `if` block: It simply checks if function output contains words other than "Workspace created".

```
x=subtask()


for issue in data['issues']:
 if len(issue['fields']['subtasks']) == 0 or x != "Workspace created":
      print issue['key']
      print issue['fields']['description']
```

It works as expected when `subtasks()` function returns any value, but fails if there is no output from function:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

How to specify default value for function if no output?
for example `x=""` I tried:

```
def subtask(x=None):
 for issue in data['issues']:
  for subtask in issue['fields']['subtasks']:
    if subtask['fields']['summary'] != 'Workspace created':
      x = subtask['fields']['summary']
    if x is None:
       x = "test"
 return x
```

But it returns "test" for tickets with and without summary fields.

Comment: Your `subtask` function and `subtask` loop variable are clashing

Comment: You're looping over `for subtask in..` which implies several subtasks? Meaning your x will keep getting changed. I guess in some cases it gets a `None`. If you just want the first subtask, just do `return subtask['fields']['summary']` instead of assigning x.

Comment: yes, several subtasks, i want to compare  `!= Workspace created` against multiple subtasks names subtask['fields']['summary'].And yes, sometimes it gets None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, if the condition `if subtask['fields']['summary'] != 'Workspace created':` never becomes true, then `x` is not initialized and thus the error of `local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`

The problem with your second code is similar, if "first if - condition" is not true there is no `x` for "second if - condition".

To fix this just set `x=None` before going into loop.

```
def subtask():
 x = None # set default value of x here
 for issue in data['issues']:
  for subtask in issue['fields']['subtasks']:
    if subtask['fields']['summary'] != 'Workspace created':
      x = subtask['fields']['summary']
 return x
```

Answer (score 0):

i simplified code (removed function)

```
data = response.json()
    for issue in data['issues']:
       for subtask in issue['fields']['subtasks']:
           s = subtask['fields']['summary']
       if len(issue['fields']['subtasks']) == 0 or subtask['fields']['summary'] != "Workspace created":
           print issue['fields']['description']
           print issue['key']
```